# VB script to copy the last digits of a columnA data and paste it as a suffix to the data in columnB

Tags: vba, excel

I need a VB script, which can copy the last 2 digits from column A and paste the same as a suffix to the data available in column B.

Ex: ColumnA     **40011.03**
    ColumnB     **Product_Revenue**

Result should be like
    ColumnA     **40011.03** 
    ColumnB     **Product_Revenue.03**

Asking for help, as I'm new to scripting.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you please share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use formula to achieve this...

```
=B1&"."&MID(A1,LEN(A1)-2,LEN(A1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With this script, you get the last two digits from the cell to the left, and paste them in the current cell, with the prefix you want:

```
Sub MacroXXX()
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(""Product_Revenue."", RIGHT(RC[-1],2))"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to create a macro using this script and i modified it a little and it works too :)